# Logic for self-calling button

Tags: if-statement, logic

I am a beginner and I am sorry in advance if I fail to make sense with my question.

I have a PLC that sends a signal that is then translated and stored in a database.
The table stores the following:
 - InvokeID  (auto increment/unique)
 - Date      (yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss)
 - Maintenance     boolean
 - Logistics       boolean

Using the above information I need to come up an if statement that would allow me to call the maintenance/logistics button each time a new signal is sent in (record is added to the data table), but it should only do so **once for each signal/record in the table.**

The buttons are on a web-page that refreshes every few seconds, so I must ensure that the if statement is called once only for each record/signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by simply comparing previous InvokeID to see if a new InvokeID exists. Sorry for wasting the time of those who have looked at the problem.